# How to make my keyboard command make the player play through the animation?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, keyboard-events

I have a problem with my keyboard commands, Im trying to make my player play an animation 
when he's walking left/right.
the keyboard gives the command for the player to move and play the animation.
the problem is that he keeps starting the animation endless times, and doesnt let it finish.

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyRelease);

```
function keyRelease(k:KeyboardEvent)
{
    movement = 0;
    gotoAndPlay("standing");
}

function keyPressed(k:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(k.keyCode==Keyboard.D)
    {
    movement = 5;
    gotoAndPlay("walking");
    }
    if(k.keyCode==Keyboard.A)
    {
    movement = -5;  
    gotoAndPlay("walking");     
    }
}
```

I imagine I can go through all the code and make some kind of long list of IFs...

but i figuerd there must be a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add events to the Keyboard, once a key is pressed, `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` is dispatched constantly if it's not released. What is likely happening is that `gotoAndPlay("walking")` is being constantly called, therefore always restarting the animation.

You need a way to check the state of the animation and avoid re-starting the sequence if it's already being played. Something like:

```
function keyRelease(k:KeyboardEvent)
{
    movement = 0;
    gotoAndPlay("standing");
}

function keyPressed(k:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(k.keyCode==Keyboard.D && movement != 5)
    {
        movement = 5;
        gotoAndPlay("walking");
    }
    if(k.keyCode==Keyboard.A && movement != -5)
    {
        movement = -5;  
        gotoAndPlay("walking");     
    }
}
```

This is not *exactly* the way I'd recommend it (figuring out the animation state from the current movement speed), but it is a simple solution and should work for this issue.

Comment: oh thanks!!!

by the time i got your response i kind of made something semilier to what you described, but i made it with timers, which made a ton of pain in the a**!
you're way seems better i'll check it right away

but is there some way to make the keyboard presses to dispatch a line of code only once?

i already imagine tons of problems in the future if i wont have this kind of option...

Comment: Not really. The keyboard event tries to mimic the way a keyboard key works - in that if you press it once, it'll dispatch a key, wait a few miliseconds, and then start dispatching that key press constantly. That's sort of expected. The best way to avoid it is to have "states" for key presses (e.g. isMovingLeft, isMovingRight), and a key down/release only change the state if it's different. Can be a bit awkward, but it works well.

Comment: As a side note, certain third party game/key input classes make it easier for you to abstract that too, and you can just check if something isPressed() rather than listening to down/up events. Or you can build your own classes to hide the repeat down/up functionality by constantly checking the state of a key before dispatching the event.

Comment: hmm... is there any source where i can learn better about this?
i might try few things out and figure it, but i can't escape the use of timers... i mean, if i say `if(keydown){isPressed}` then he is just going to dispatch the same function every frame, thanks again you're very helpful!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using it for, but I'd *definitely* avoid the use of timers. Unless they're for long-term (1sec+) stuff, they're really imprecise and a resource hog. And you're right, if `isKeyPressed(whatever)` is a problem for player movement animation, it would force a check of the state just so it wouldn't start the animation again. You'll probably need some boolean vars (e.g. `isWalkingLeft`). But it still helps under other situations. This tutorial seems to have a good introduction on using keyboard states on games: http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/1299072

Comment: niiiice! thanks ill read it, i hope it'll make some sense for me :)